# How can I use map.keySet() and map.values() in one SOQL?

Tags: apex, soql, map, bulkification

I have a map like this: `Map<ID,List<ID>> invs = new Map<ID,List<ID>>();`.
I am trying to delete like this:
`delete [SELECT ID FROM Invoice__Share WHERE ParentId IN :invs.keySet() AND UserOrGroupId IN :invs.values()];`
How can I do this in the most elegant way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `Map.values` directly if the value is a `List`. Instead, you need to flatten that `List<List>` down before using it.

```
List<Id> values = new List<Id>();
for (List<Id> value : myMap.values())
    values.addAll(value);
```

Alternatively, you can keep this flattened structure and update it whenever you update the map itself. Whether one is more elegant than the other is hard to say, without knowing more about the structure of your code. The benefit of this approach is that if you need to pass the data to some other method for processing, you can keep it as one parameter.